# Why I got the next errors?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

could someone help me with this error please:

Output for command: `systemctl start postgresql-13.service`

```
Job for postgresql-13.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status postgresql-13.service" and "journalctl -xeu postgresql-13.service" for details.
```

Output for command `systemctl status postgresql-13.service`

```
× postgresql-13.service - PostgreSQL 13 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-13.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-08-23 12:17:50 CDT; 1min 47s ago
       Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/static/
    Process: 1079 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-13/bin/postgresql-13-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1110 ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-13/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1110 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 40ms

Aug 23 12:17:47 fedora systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 13 database server...
Aug 23 12:17:50 fedora postmaster[1110]: 2022-08-23 12:17:50.144 CDT [1110] LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
Aug 23 12:17:50 fedora postmaster[1110]: 2022-08-23 12:17:50.144 CDT [1110] HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
Aug 23 12:17:50 fedora systemd[1]: postgresql-13.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 23 12:17:50 fedora systemd[1]: postgresql-13.service: Killing process 1132 (postmaster) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 23 12:17:50 fedora systemd[1]: postgresql-13.service: Killing process 1132 (postmaster) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 23 12:17:50 fedora systemd[1]: postgresql-13.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 12:17:50 fedora systemd[1]: postgresql-13.service: Unit process 1132 (postmaster) remains running after unit stopped.
Aug 23 12:17:50 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 13 database server.
```

Already I uninstall and reinstall postgresql but nothing works. Also I tried to install postgresql-14 but I get the same error.
I have to install postgresql to work alongs with Ruby on Rails.

Comment: You have any good entries in your `log` directory? I'm guessing that may be in `/var/log/postgresql/` This info you posted just says there was an error, but I'm betting there is some useful information hiding in a log file.

Comment: I don't know why but, for some reason, I don't have the postgresql dir into /var/log dir, I'll try to install it again.

Comment: I don't think reinstalling is going to change anything. I was guessing at where your postgres log may reside. Read the manual for your platform/install and see where that is at. As for this question, you may get some more traction if you take it over to dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I already reinstall postgresql-14 completely, and now I can start postgresql service.

Comment: I don't know what it was happened, but maybe an error during the installation that I don't saw.